# Verilog: Why the register synchroinized the input data in the same clock cycle?

Tags: verilog

I am creating a simple register buffering the input data. Both input data and the register are synchronized by the clk.

```
always  @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)begin
    if(rst_n==1'b0)begin
        reg1 <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        reg1 <= in1;
    end
end
```

It is anticipated that the value of reg1 should be equal to in1 of previous clk cycle. e.g.

```
cc     0    1     2     3     4

in1    00   01    02    03   ...

reg1   00   00    01    02   ...
```

While in the simulation,  the result shows that reg1 equals to in1 in every clock cycle

```
cc     0    1     2     3     4

in1    00   01    02    03   ...

reg1   00   01    02    03   ...
```

What is the reason for this? How would I modify the code or testbench to generate the anticipated result?

The Minimal, Reproducible Example is given here

```
//buffer.v
module buffer(
    input
          clk,
          rst_n,
          [7:0] in1,
    output reg
          [7:0] out1
);
always  @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)begin
    if(rst_n==1'b0)begin
        out1 <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        out1 <= in1;
    end
end
endmodule
```

```
//buffer_tb.v
`timescale 1 ns/10 ps

module buffer_tb;

reg clk,rst_n;
reg [7:0] in1;
wire [7:0] out1;

localparam period = 20;
buffer bf0(
      .clk  ( clk    ),
      .rst_n( rst_n  ),
      .in1  ( in1    ),
      .out1 ( out1   )
);

//clk,rst_n generation
initial begin
    clk = 1'b0;
    rst_n = 1'b0;
    #20  //
    rst_n = 1'b1;
end
always #10 clk = ~clk;

//Data generation
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    in1 = 8'd0;
    #period
    in1 = 8'd1;
    #period
    in1 = 8'd2;
    #period
    in1 = 8'd3;
    #period
    in1 = 8'd0;
end

endmodule
```

```
# run.do
# Fortsätt köra trots rapporterade fel:
set BreakOnAssertion 3

# Definiera design (både entity och filer):
set design buffer

# Kompilera koden:
vlib work
vlog -93 ${design}.v
vlog -93 ${design}_tb.v

# Ladda in koden i simulatorn:
vsim -voptargs=+acc ${design}_tb

add wave -position insertpoint  \\
sim:/buffer_tb/clk \\
sim:/buffer_tb/in1 \\
sim:/buffer_tb/out1

# Kör tills det inte finns något kvar att simulera:
run 160ns

# Zooma wave-fönstret så att allt syns:
wave zoom full
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is you are using blocking assignment (`=`) on `in1` at the same timestamp at the posedge clock.

The preferred solution is to use non-blocking assignment (`<=`) on `in1`. This post-pones the updated to `in1` so that it pre-updated value will be sampled in the clock edge.

Since you have a clock, I recommend updating `in1` on the clock event and not a `#` delay of a matching period. If the numbers do not exactly match, or if there is an rounding error, or start modeling clock jitter/frequency change, or use a PLL, etc. Then your timeing events will not line up and possible start to drift to a point an sample is missed. Instead it is good to get into the have of using the clocking event as your main delay.

You should change this:

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    in1 = 8'd0;
    #period
    in1 = 8'd1;
    #period
    in1 = 8'd2;
    #period
    in1 = 8'd3;
    #period
    in1 = 8'd0;
end
```

To this (or something similar):

```
initial begin
  repeat(4) begin
    @(posedge clk)  in1 <= 8'd0;
    @(posedge clk)  in1 <= 8'd1;
    @(posedge clk)  in1 <= 8'd2;
    @(posedge clk)  in1 <= 8'd3;
    @(posedge clk)  in1 <= 8'd0;
  end
end
```